# Setup test environment using Selendroid, Selenium Grid in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, selenium-webdriver, selendroid, ui-testing, selenium-grid2

Just a quick one, I want to setup test environment for mobile testing using Selenium Grid, Selendroid in the android Studio environment. Does anyone have detail tutorial, video or a presentation that can serve for easy learning?

Comment: Here easy steps are available : http://selendroid.io/setup.html

Comment: One more easy tutorial : http://www.ontestautomation.com/up-and-running-with-selendroid/

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate. I think they are both very good to kickstart.